# Can we implement a personal note to a Favorite Question?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

Asked first in WordPress.SE.com:

Many times, we do *Favorite* Questions in SE Networks for our future use. But what we got, a list of Titles of Questions in our personal profile. I wonder sometimes I get lost into the very titles — because some of the titles are not clearly saying what they are, or what they contains, or some of the Answers may contain something "extraordinary" that not just mentioned in the Question label.

So I'm thinking of implementing a "Personal Note" — whenever we will try to Favorite a Question, a popup `<textarea>` will appear to contain a limited amount of texts (i.e. 300 characters); and that will be visible beside the Question Labels on the list of Favorite Questions, so that it'd be easy for a user to find out which Questions was favored (?) and why that was favored exactly.

But the Notes will be Optional — can be skipped on the process of favoring a Question.

So,
Can we implement "Personal Notes" to Favorite Questions?

Comment: @JoshC What does that have to do with it?  It's not a publicly shared notation, merely a private notation of why that question is worth favoriting.

Comment: I would like to be able to categorize (tag?) favorite questions.  Allow them to be organized in some way.

Comment: @Servy I'm afraid, the preceding comment was deleted, on which you commented that out.

Comment: High cost, low benefit.

Comment: I'd prefer a private list, independent from favorites, with an additional numeric field for own categories for e.g. follow up, first troll suspect etc.

Comment: Agree! That would be kinda useful!

Comment: In the meantime, there is a feature called [saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info), it was announced here: [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019). 
For each saved post you can add a note up to 500 characters. Currently both saves and the notes are private - see [this related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391888).

Answer (score 4):

I think we should be able to have personal annotations on any questions and answers.  This would make SO an even more valuable resource.  Naturally, it works best for favorite questions, since you'll have a list of these, but they could implement a list of your personal notations, so you could go back to the questions or answers that you put them on.

Comment: Yes! Most often I am missing personal notes when I am preparing to extend my old answer. I need a place to collect references and notes for the future edit. --- It could even be a a normal comment - just visible to me. Missing edit functionality can be overcome by deleting and recreating the comment.