# Allow setting public visibility settings on saves lists, such as "public" and "unlisted"

Tags: feature-request, saves

This idea is based on YouTube playlist / Google Drive share link visibility settings, which allow "private", "unlisted" (only people with the link can view), and "public".

For most of my saves lists, I don't care about them being private, and actually could potentially find it useful if I could share them with others.

For example,

- I have a list for feature-requests I want to see implemented. If I could make this public, I could show people what I care about.
- I have a list for guidance I often give to other users that isn't as well covered in the Help Center. Imagine if I could just throw the entire thing at a new user who's curious about learning the network more deeply?
- I have a list on SO of ChatGPT posts that I still want to take certain actions on. I could share this with "unlisted" visibility to other users in the AI Domination chat room and AI heuristics group.
- I currently put a list of answers I'm proud of on my SO profile, but the character length limitation is a real pain in the butt. If I could stuff those into a saves list and just link that in my profile, that would be nice. Of course, I could just workaround that by hosting the list somewhere else like a GitHub Gist, but I've kind of gotten brainwashed into having a thing against off-site links.
- I just saw [Collections: A New Feature for Collectives on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425872/11107541) (which lists motivations such as "resource showcase" and "content maintenance" (which I've touched on in my examples above)) and thought to myself- "if we could make public saves lists, basically anyone could do something akin to this" (except without collaborative editing I guess).

Comment: Asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382569/152859) without any staff response.

Comment: The only concern I have is that people suck and someone's going to create a list with an offensive title. However, even if lists couldn't have public titles I think this would be pretty useful.

Comment: Related: [How can I download my "saves" lists?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391982/323179). There are workarounds there that might be helpful.

Comment: @Laurel uh... debatable. I don't want to deal with the implementation details of where and how I store this stuff and keeping my "off-site" storage up to date with saves lists. so really I don't think that's that helpful at all for my use-cases. I was also already aware of that Q&A. but maybe it'll help others, so thanks.